# Como invertir el orden de un eje de fechas en ggplot?

Tags: r, date, ggplot2

Quiero hacer un grafico de columnas, logré que se vea bien usando el comando "coord_flip()", el problema es que esto me invierte los ejes también y no se como hacer para invertir el eje que tiene fechas para que comienze (en la parte de arriba) con la fecha mas antigua y termine en la mas nueva.

hay otra forma de hacer un grafico de columnas? o es que hay una manera de revertir el eje?

dejo el código de lo que estoy usando

```
ggplot(data=tiemposXdia, aes(x=Fecha, y=avg)) + 
  ggtitle ("Tiempos de Respuesta")+ 
  xlab("por dia") + 
  ylab("Tiempo en minutos") + 
  geom_col(inherit.aes = TRUE) +
  coord_flip() +
  scale_x_date(date_labels = '%d/%b', date_breaks = "2 days")
```

Comment: ¿Podrías agregar la salida de este comando `str(tiemposXdia)` a tu pregunta?

Answer (score 0):

En el post [Reversing scale_datetime](https://groups.google.com/g/ggplot2/c/qrcvqy6TdzI) el código de Hadley Wickham invierte el sentido de la escala tipo fecha (`POSIXct`). Sin embargo, tiene algunos detalles distintos a los de este caso. El primero es que lo usa en el eje `y`, el segundo es que no admite los parámetros `date_labels` y `date_breaks`.

El primer detalle se soluciona simplemente cambiando la función `scale_y_continuous` por `scale_x_continuous`.

El segundo fue un poco más complicado de resolver y podría ser tema de otra pregunta, aún así, propongo una solución arcaica con el uso de la función `labels` y `breaks`.

El siguiente código genere un gráfico de tipo columna en cuyo eje x se revierte el orden de las fechas.

```
#Cargamos las librerias
library(ggplot2)
library(scales)

#Simulamos datos
set.seed(124)
date <- paste(   "2015/03/" , 1:10 , sep="")
value <- sample(seq(1,100) , 10)
data <- data.frame(date,value)
# Use as.Date en lugar de as.POSIXct
data$date<-as.Date(data$date)
data

#Código de Hadley Wickham
c_trans <- function(a, b, breaks = b$breaks, format = b$format) {
  a <- as.trans(a)
  b <- as.trans(b)

  name <- paste(a$name, b$name, sep = "-")

  trans <- function(x) a$trans(b$trans(x))
  inv <- function(x) b$inverse(a$inverse(x))

  trans_new(name, trans, inverse = inv, breaks = breaks, format=format)
}

# Generamos una nueva tranformación de escala
# que invierte una escala tipo fecha
# Si usa el formato "POSIXct" cambie "data" por "time" en seguida 
rev_date <- c_trans("reverse", "date")

#ver ggplot2 ggplot2:::datetime_scale
labels <- function(self, x) {
    tz <- if (is.null(self$timezone)) 
        "UTC"
    else self$timezone
    date_format('%d/%b', tz)(x)
}

# Función ad hoc para generar los saltos
brk<-function(x,width){
    x<-x[order(x)]
    x<-x[seq(width,length(x),width)]
    return(x)
}

#Generamos los saltos para el eje x
breaks<-brk(data$date,2)

ggplot(data,aes(x=date,y=value))+
    ggtitle ("Tiempos de Respuesta")+ 
    xlab("por dia") + 
    ylab("Tiempo en minutos") + 
    geom_col(inherit.aes = TRUE) +
    coord_flip() +
    #Aplicamos la tranformación de escala a la grafica
    scale_x_continuous(trans = rev_date,
        labels = labels,
        breaks = breaks)
```